# XCode Cannot Run Deployed Watch Apps: dyld: warning: could not load inserted library

Tags: xcode, xcode8, dyld, watchos-3, watchos-simulator

My XCode installation has something wrong with it and I have not been able to fix it.  Anytime I run any Watch App in the simulator, the Phone and the watch simulator will open, but when the Watch App runs, my Mac crashes and reboots.  I am running XCode 8.2.1 on OSX Sierra 10.12.3 (16D32).  The error below seems to indicate it may be grabbing a version of a library that is not suitable for the watch I am trying to run the app with.  Below are the things I have tried so far as well as the warning message I am seeing.

- Complete re-install of 8.2.1 (removed all cached files and simulators as well)
- Installed 8.3.5 BETA
- Rebooted Machine

  dyld: warning: could not load inserted library '/usr/local/lib/dgagent/libpreload.dylib' because no suitable image found.  Did find:
      /usr/local/lib/dgagent/libpreload.dylib: mach-o, but not built for watchOS simulator

NOTE: the warning message is only present in XCode 8.3.5 BETA, not in 2.1, but running any Watch App will crash my machine with either version of XCode.